# AWS Cognito: Trying to Alert User of Error

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am having difficulty in capturing a Cognito Sign Up Error. I am trying to alert the user when Cognito returns a "UsernameExistsException","message":"User already exists" Error. 
Below is my code:

```
self.pool!.signUp(usernameTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!, userAttributes: attributes,   validationData: nil).continue(successBlock: { (task:AWSTask!) in
                // needs to be async so we can ALWAYS return nil for AWSTask
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if task.error != nil {  // some sort of error
                        let myerror = task.error
                        print("\(myerror)")
                        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Sign Up Error", message: (task.error?.localizedDescription)! as String, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
                        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
                    else    {
                        let response: AWSCognitoIdentityUserPoolSignUpResponse = task.result! as AWSCognitoIdentityUserPoolSignUpResponse
                        // NSLog("AWSCognitoIdentityUserPoolSignUpResponse: \(response)")
                        self.user = response.user
                        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Sign Up Successful", message: "", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { action in self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "confrimationSegue", sender: self) }))
                        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

                    }
                }
                return nil
            })
```

For some reason  am unable to break into the task.error != nil conditional statement. When I force an error the error does not print and alert action does not present to the view. Am I attempting to alert the user in the wrong function? How else can I check for the Username Already Exists error presented by cognito.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a `successBlock`, which means that the block that you set is only going to be called when the sign up was performed succesfully. That's why the error is always `nil`.

In order to have the error, you should set the callback simply by something like the following:

```
userPool
    .signUp(user.email, password: user.password, userAttributes: attributes, validationData: nil)
    .continue({ response in
        if let error = response.error {
           // Error ocurred
        } else {
           // No error ocurred
        })
```

This continue method only recieves the callback and will be called when a error happens.